# Did Paul consider Peter as the Leader of the Church?

Tags: paul-apostle, peter, apostolic-succession

From whichever theologies hold Peter to have been the first and highest authority in the visible Church I would like two questions answered, please.  Please indicate which tradition you are speaking from.

1)  Paul appears (under inspiration of the Spirit) indifferent to whatever reputation may have been ascribed to James, Peter, and John.  *Galatians 2:6 - "And from those who seemed to be influential (what they were makes no difference to me; God shows no partiality)—those, I say, who seemed influential added nothing to me."*

If Paul recognized Peter as the highest authority why say 'seemed to be influential' and 'makes no difference to me'?

2) In Acts 15 Paul goes to the Jerusalem council and, although Peter speaks, James has the last word and announces his judgement:  "Therefore my judgment is that we should not trouble those of the Gentiles who turn to God" - Acts 15:19

If Peter was leader in this Church council, why did James take what appears to be the role of leader in speaking last and in elucidating his judgement?

Comment: Food for thought. The word [pope](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/12260a.htm#V) has undergone various usages historically. The most noteworthy of the titles are Papa, Summus Pontifex, Pontifex Maximus, Etc.. The title pope was, as has been stated, at one time employed with far more latitude. In the East it has always been used to designate simple priests. In the Western Church, however, it seems from the beginning to have been restricted to bishops (Tertullian, On Modesty 13). It was apparently in the fourth century that it began to become a distinctive title of the Roman Pontiff.

Comment: You may wish to ask if St. Paul considered Peter as the one who was head of the Church, on earth?

Comment: ***”Please indicate which tradition you are speaking from.”*** This is an opinion that varies by denomination and is too broad. This is not a forum.

Comment: It would be better to explicitly direct this just to the Catholic Church.

Comment: This is the question as I understand it: "Gal 2 and Acts 15 make it seem like Peter wasn't the first Pope.  Do those who believe Peter was the first Pope have an answer to these verses?"

Comment: @zippy2006 That is essentially what I am asking (although I have edited the title Pope out of the question).  I also wish to ascertain if there is a difference between Roman Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy, for example, and so did not direct the question to a single tradition.

Comment: Your question contains an anachronism: the term Pope/Papa did not come into common usage for the leader of The Church until a few centuries later.  Your question seems to be actually a question about whether or not Peter, or James, was the head of the church.  I will suggest that you edit your question and ask just one question. Your further comment about differences between Roman Catholic and Eastern Orthodoxy is also a Separate Question.  Please respect the stack format: one answerable question per question. (And it is fine, even encouraged, to ask multiple questions)

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I've edited out the word Pope.  Thank you for the suggestion.  My question is actually, if Peter was the head of the church, how can these two things be explained?  Should I ask each question separately to both the Roman and Eastern traditions?

Comment: Seeing that this question is asking the information from various churches, I removed the Catholicism tag. It does not appear to be a question directly asking a Catholic perspective exclusively.

Comment: Hmm, I am showing Pope still in the title, not sure what's going on, so I edited the title.  Does that still capture your intent? @KenGraham I think this is getting into the kind of shape to reopen ... but may need some more tweaking?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I am OK with this now. If others vote to reopen it, I will join in. For now, I would like to see if others feel that way also.

Comment: I will separate these out into individual questions.